# Resources to get started on Philosophy

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I want to know if there is a possibility of having a sort of list of resources to get started on philosophy, both in general (which is what I am interested in right now) and in particular themes. I ask this, because in MetaJapanese SE there is a [list](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) that provides several resources, on several formats.

I know that learning Japanese and studying Philosophy are completely different, but I wanted to know if there are some books generally regarded as good for an introduction to general Philosophy.

Thank you.

Comment: Does [this question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/256/where-and-how-can-i-get-started-in-contemporary-philosophy) or [this one](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/how-to-get-started-with-philosophy-without-getting-overwhelmed-quickly) not quite have what you're looking for?